# Objective-C C++ wrapper Incomplete definition of type error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, wrapper, objective-c++

Iam trying to write Objective-c wrappers for existing C++ classes. 
I have Objective-c header in Click.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Fundation.h> 
@class CClick; // forward declaration of C++ class
@interface Click : NSObject
@end
```

Then I have implementation of wrapper in Click.mm:

```
#import "CClick.h"// import of C++ 
#import "Click.h" // objc import
@interface Click ()
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CClick *clickInternal;
@end
@implementation Click
... 
- (NSString *) uri
{
const char* uri = self.clickInternal->getUri(); // here I have error with incomplete definition of type 'CClick'
```

CClick is my C++ class, that has just some properties and getter for them.

When I try to build my project I get: **incomplete definition of type 'CClick'**

getUri method definition in CClick.h in c++:

```
#include <string> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace MyTest {

class CClick {

public:
    string uri;
    string id;

    string getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    string getId() {
        return id;
    }
};

}
```

Comment: incomplete definition of type 'CClick'

Comment: Please add more information like `clickInternal`, `getUri` method and how `CClick.h` looks like.

Comment: As I know, to forward declaration of C++ class, you need to use `class CClick`. `@class CClick` is used for Objective-C class. Make sure that you understand what are you doing. Implementation file should be `.mm`. And add `CClick.h` file if you want another help.

Comment: Thanks @trungduc for pointing out '@class' vs 'class'. I've also updated my question, added necessary description. Currently i get Member access into incomplete type 'CClick' error...

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a very bad idea. Using it in a header file is inviting disaster for yourself and anyone who includes your poisonous header file. You need to stop that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you forgot to using `CClick` with `namespace MyTest`. Check my below code.

```
#import <Foundation/Fundation.h>
namespace MyTest {
class CClick; // forward declaration of C++ class
}
@interface Click : NSObject
@end
```

Implementation file.

```
@interface Click ()
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyTest::CClick *clickInternal;
@end
```

Or simply, add `using namespace MyTest;`

*Important note from @Richard Hodges:*

> `using namespace std;` is a very bad idea. Using it in a header file is inviting disaster for yourself and anyone who includes your poisonous header file. You need to stop that right now.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot to include MyTest namespace :)

Comment: You should take a look at Richard Hodges's comment. It's really good for you.

Answer (score 0):

To write a Wrapper class you have to create a `.mm` class. It is unclear from your Question if your implementation is nested in a .mm class. This tells the compiler your class wants to access (or contains) c++ code. (Google Objective-C++)

Untested pseudo example. C++ Class Foo and Wrapper class Bar.

Objective C Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Fundation.h>     
@interface Bar : NSObject
+ (NSString *) myString;
@end
```

Objective C++ Implementation:

```
#include "Foo.h"
@implementation Bar
 + (NSString *) myString{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: Foo::getMyString().c_str()];
}
@end
```

Pitfalls:

- The header should not contain any C++ Code / References. Otherwise you will only be able to import it into Objective-C++ classes.
- Type Conversions can be a pain. Always cast primitive Type conversions.

How to handle object relations and Lifecycles. E.g. when to delete your C++ Object if it is held within a Objective-C Object is a different topic, but something you should think about - this is why I used a static call in my example.